# Can't edit my JTable data with setValueAt()

Tags: java, swing, jtable, overriding, edit

After spending my afternoon trying to find a solution, I finally created an account to ask my question and I hope someone can help me.

I'm creating a JTable in an internal frame. I have my own tableModel and cellRenderer (because i want the user to be able to edit only the cells of the borders of the table, and I want the uneditable cells to be grey). It works fine, the uneditable cells are grey and we can't clic on it. The others, we can clic on it BUT when we modify the value and press enter, nothing happen, the value get back to default.
I tried to modify the cell value in the code with the "setValueAt()" method but i doesn't work either.

I tried to implement some listener but nothing worked :/. Can you help me please? I hope I'm clear enough. Here's my code to help:

MyCellRenderer.java (working perfectly)

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableCellRenderer;

public class MyCellRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer {
    @Override
    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(
    JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected,
    boolean hasFocus, int row, int column){
        if (table.isCellEditable(row, column)) {
           setBackground(Color.white);
        }
        else {
           setBackground(Color.darkGray);
        }

        return super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected,
                                                   hasFocus, row, column);
   }
}
```

MyTableModel.java (working perfectly)

```
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

public class MyTableModel extends DefaultTableModel{
    public boolean[][] canEdit = new boolean[][]{};

    public void setEditModel(int maxRow, int maxCol){
        canEdit = new boolean[maxRow][maxCol];
        for(int col=0;col< maxCol; col++){
            for(int row=0;row< maxRow; row++){
                if(col == 0 || row == 0 || col == maxCol-1){
                    canEdit[row][col] = true;
                }
                else{
                    canEdit[row][col] = false;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCellEditable(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
        return canEdit[rowIndex][columnIndex];
    }
}
```

Here's a part of my main frame. When I press this Button, it create the table in the internal frame

```
private void jButtonValiderTailleCuisineActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                            

    MyTableModel dataModel;
    dataModel = new MyTableModel() {
            @Override public int getColumnCount() { return jSliderLongueur.getValue(); }
            @Override public int getRowCount() { return jSliderLargeur.getValue();}
            @Override public Object getValueAt(int row, int col) { return 0; }
        };
        table = new JTable(dataModel);
        dataModel.setEditModel(jSliderLargeur.getValue(), jSliderLongueur.getValue());
        table.setDragEnabled(false);
        table.setTableHeader(null);
        table.setCellSelectionEnabled(true);
        table.setRowSelectionAllowed(false);
        table.setColumnSelectionAllowed(false);
        table.setRowHeight(40);
        TableColumn column;
        for (int i = 0; i < jSliderLongueur.getValue(); i++) {
            column = table.getColumnModel().getColumn(i);
            column.setMinWidth(40);
            column.setMaxWidth(40);
        }
        System.out.println(dataModel.getValueAt(5, 5));

        JPanel m_rootPanel = new JPanel();
        JScrollPane jScrollPane1 = new JScrollPane(table);
        m_rootPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        jInternalFramePourTableau.setContentPane(m_rootPanel);
        m_rootPanel.add(jScrollPane1, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        for (int i =0; i<dataModel.getColumnCount();i++) {
            table.setDefaultRenderer(table.getColumnClass(i), new MyCellRenderer());
        }

        table.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
            int row = table.rowAtPoint(evt.getPoint());
            int col = table.columnAtPoint(evt.getPoint());
            if (row >= 0 && col >= 0) {
                selectedCell[0] = row;
                selectedCell[1] = col;
                System.out.println("Vous avez cliquez en: " + selectedCell[0] + " " + selectedCell[1]);
            }
        }
    });

        jSliderLongueur.setEnabled(false);
        jSliderLargeur.setEnabled(false);
        jButtonValiderTailleCuisine.setEnabled(false);
}
```

It works, but I can't edit the cells which are not grey. So the problem is maybe the way I create my table.

Here's my not working code (it's when i press this button, It must change the value of the selected cell with the value "TEST"):

```
private void jButtonChangeValueActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                
        System.out.println("CurrentCellSelected: " + selectedCell[0] + " " + selectedCell[1]);//it is the correct selectedCell
        dataModel.setValueAt("TEST", selectedCell[0], selectedCell[1]);//NOT WORKING
    }
```

When I clicked the button "jButtonChangeValueActionPerformed", the line dataModel.setValueAt(...) does nothing.

I really hope someone can help me, I wasted so much time trying to find a solution.

Good evening everyone.

Comment: `jButtonChangeValueActionPerformed()` isn't a button, it's a method.  You need to add an `ActionListener` to your button with a proper `actionPerformed()` method.  It doesn't seem like you've included to code where you create your button, though, so I'm not sure exactly what that would look like.

Comment: @azurefrog Yeah I misswrite that, but it's not the problem, i want to change the value when the action is performed, it's linked to a jComboBox but I simplify that part cause it's not important. Thank you anyway!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I solved it.
I just commented the line:

```
        //public Object getValueAt(String value, int row, int col) { return value; }
```

in my main frame class, where I create my JTable, and now it works fine!

In conclusion: Overriding the method "getValueAt()" set the method "setValueAt()" unusable. (in my case).

```
dataModel = new MyTableModel() {
            @Override public int getColumnCount() { return jSliderLongueur.getValue(); }
            @Override public int getRowCount() { return jSliderLargeur.getValue();}
            //public Object getValueAt(String value, int row, int col) { return value; }
        };
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok I added that:

```
table.getModel().addTableModelListener(new TableModelListener() {
        public void tableChanged(TableModelEvent e) {

            table.getModel().removeTableModelListener(this);
            System.out.println("TABLE CHANGED");
            table.setValueAt("TEST", selectedCell[0], selectedCell[1]);
            table.getModel().addTableModelListener(this);
        }
    });
```

and now it call this method just once. But it doesn't resolve my problem, the data is still unmodifiable.

I assume that the problem is the method setValueAt(). This method, wherever I call it, doesn't work. I don't know I have to override it like I overrided TableModel. Or if I have to call some redraw-table method?

EDIT:
I tried to override the setValueAt() method but it's useless, like I was thinking...

```
import java.util.Vector;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableModel;

public class MyTableModel extends DefaultTableModel{
    public boolean[][] canEdit = new boolean[][]{
        /*{true, true, true, true, true, true},
        {true, false, false, false, false, true},
        {true, false, false, false, false, true},
        {true, false, false, false, false, true},
        {true, false, false, false, false, true},
        {true, false, false, false, false, true}*/
    };
        TableModel model;

    public void setEditModel(int maxRow, int maxCol){
        canEdit = new boolean[maxRow][maxCol];
        for(int col=0;col< maxCol; col++){
            for(int row=0;row< maxRow; row++){
                if(col == 0 || row == 0 || col == maxCol-1){
                    canEdit[row][col] = true;
                }
                else{
                    canEdit[row][col] = false;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCellEditable(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
        return canEdit[rowIndex][columnIndex];
    }
    //useless override cause it's the same definition in DefaultTableModel
    @Override
    public void setValueAt(Object value, int row, int column) 
    {
        ((Vector) dataVector.get(row)).set(column, value);
        fireTableCellUpdated(row, column);
    }
}
```

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash in my button method, under the table creation. 

But the problem isn't the listener. The problem is the fact that table.setValueAt() is not working.